# Create non private component by DesignerHost.CreateComponent

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Good day!

How can I create component by `IDesignerHost.CreateComponent` with non-private modifier? By default components/controls are created as private. Is there any way to override such behavior?

Comment: What do you mean it is private? What needs access to it?

Comment: @Alan, component that is created by `DesignerHost.CreateComponent` is always private by default when it is serialized in `InitializeComponent`. My question is - how to change that behavior?

Comment: Can you describe more about what type of control is being added to what? Typically.. I would have a TabControl, for example, and the Designerhost would create Tabs for it perhaps, but those tabs would belong to a TabCollection that was public and therefore accessible. You are adding design time support for a custom control?

Comment: @Alan, I'm converting "old" controls(ComboBox'es) to "new" ones. I've wrote vsix that does all conversion job. When user opens designer and selects Form or UserControl, vsix detects old controls presence and suggests to convert them. I need to preserve old controls access modifiers.